# Проблема с базой данных Python

Tags: python, база-данных

Знакомлюсь с БД **PostgreSQL** в Python. Ввёл код для бд PostgreSQL с сайта: https://python-scripts.com/database

Вот сам код для бд PostgreSQL:

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='my_database', user='username')
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Выполняем запрос.
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table_name")
row = cursor.fetchone()

# Закрываем подключение.
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Но в PyCharm выводится ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/main/ex_2.py", line 3, in <module>
    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='my_database', user='username')
  File "C:\Python3.8.2\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Может нужно где-то еще регистрироваться, вводить пароль и тд, а потом как-т связывать бд и код в пайчарме? Подскажите, как решить это.

Comment: В ошибке все английским по белому написано. У вас запущен сервер PostrgreSQL?

Comment: А как запустить этот сервер?

Comment: Начнём с того, что его ещё установить нужно.

Comment: Зайти на сайт и почитать документацию?

Comment: Подскажите, получается нужно скачать базу данных, например тут: http://vvs.ru/pg/notes-ru.htm и там ввожу свой пароль и логин. А после этого, если запущу код в пайчарме, то будет работать?

Comment: Судя по Вашим недавним вопросам, Вы не знакомы с БД. Тогда могу посоветовать Вам `SQLite`. Это лёгкая БД, которая не требует запуска и отдельной установки, а модуль для работы с ней уже есть в `Python`.

Comment: Спасибо большое, но необходимо работать исключительно с PostrgreSQL (